# When changing color on conditional errormessage in javascript, it becomes visible on page load

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page returned from Azure, and I want to change the colour of an error message(UsernameIsMissing) to red on a div element inside the azure generated HTML page.

The error message should only be shown if the Username is missing and the Save button is clicked. I have created an API div inside a (local) HTML page, this API div element is being replaced by the HTML page returned from Azure.

My problem is that when I am changing the text colour on the error message to red, it will show the error message on page load instead of after the click event. What do I need to do in order to make the error message visible only after the click event?

```
<div id="api"></div> 
<script> 
 window.onload = changeColor(); 
 function changeColor() { 
   var errorMsg = document.getElementById('UsernameIsMissing'); 
   erroMsg.style = "color:red;"; 
 } 
</script>
```

UPDATE:

I eventually figured it out. I have added a second function that adds an eventlistener for the click event on the button. that calls the changeColor function.

```
<div id="api"></div> 
<script> 
 window.onload = SaveBtnClickEvent();

 function SaveBtnClickEvent() { 
   var saveBtn = document.getElementById('SaveButton'); 
   saveBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){changeColor();});

 function changeColor() { 
   var errorMsg = document.getElementById('UsernameIsMissing'); 
   erroMsg.style = "color:red;"; 
 } 
</script>
```

I have tried this change before, but it was not working because of one small mistake on the second parameter:

```
saveBtn.addEventListener("click", changeColor(); );
```

instead the second parameter should be like shown below:

```
saveBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){changeColor();});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a boolean local variable clicked=false. Then after the user clicks the button, update the variable to true. At changeColor function check the state of the variable

```
let clicked = false;

//When the user clicks the button also make clicked = true;

<div id="api"></div> 
<script> 
  window.onload = changeColor(); 
  function changeColor() { 
    if (clicked){
      var errorMsg = document.getElementById('UsernameIsMissing'); 
      erroMsg.style = "color:red;"; 
    }
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: how does changeColor get invoked when the button is pushed? How do you set click = true?